# Cannot resolve method 'getLifecycle' in 'Allure'

Tags: java, allure

I have project in java and i am using Allure for generating a test report.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550444/allure-testng-custom-test-method-names-while-using-dataprovider) and I need to rename my test using the below code:

```
AllureLifecycle lifecycle = Allure.getLifecycle();
//change test name to "CHANGED_NAME"
lifecycle.updateTestCase(testResult -> testResult.setName("CHANGED_NAME"));
```

I have imported the AllureLifecycle  from below:

```
import io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle;
```

and using the below dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
  <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
  <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But, in the line `Allure.getLifecycle()` it is complaining with `Cannot resolve method 'getLifecycle' in 'Allure'`.

How can fix the error?

Comment: Did you also `import io.qameta.allure.Allure;` ?

Comment: @AlexShesterov it fixes my problem. Thanks.
But actually `lifecycle.updateTestCase(testResult -> testResult.setName("CHANGED_NAME"));` does not rename my test. 

Do you have an answer for this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550444/allure-testng-custom-test-method-names-while-using-dataprovider

Answer (score 0):

You need to add import of `io.qameta.allure.Allure` class